# How to figure out error and placement in React Native

Tags: javascript, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I have an app which has react native modules working with iOS swift code , I am receiving an error of the type shown in image. Here I see no file name of the actual code file and no details of error neither the description. How one can debug such errors ? Even in the chrome extension same details are displayed .

Any help or direction will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an exception was thrown in an async executed code and no `.catch()` did handle the rejection.

And React Native Debugging docs  http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#content